# Carry forward values in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, window-functions, lag

I have a requirement to carry forward values from `Col_Value` based on last `Col_Date` (based on partition by logic on the columns `Col_1,Col_2,Col_3,Col_4`). When there a value in the current row, we should not carry forward and use current value else carry forward from the previous date. If there is no value in the current row and for previous date, then we should use the last recent carry forwarded value.

Here's my input table.

[image]

Below is the sql I tried so far.

```
select *,
case 
    when col_value is null 
        then lag(Col_Value) over (PARTITION BY Col_1,Col_2,Col_3,Col_4 order by Col_Date) 
    else col_value
end as Carry_Fowrard_Value
from carry_table
```

I used the `lag` analytical function and was able to get below results based on the sql I shared above. But I am getting null for the highlighted rows as there are no values for the previous date. How do I carry forward the value based on last available value?

[image]

Below is the expected output.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: tabular form is much better choice than attaching images.

Comment: @zealous. Noted. Going forward, I will give in tabular form rather than images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following - first get the count of `NULL` values and then fill those nulls it with `max()` value within that partition.

Here is the **[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nRb3ypBoN9VNgHg5rGzfn7/2)** in PostgreSQL though, but should work in hive as well.

```
select
  Col_1, 
  Col_2, 
  Col_3, 
  Col_4, 
  Col_Date,
  Col_Value,
  coalesce(Col_Value, max(Col_Value) over (partition by Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4, rn)) as Carry_Forward_Value
from
(
  select
      *,
      count(Col_Value) over (partition by Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4 order by Col_Date) as rn
  from carry_table
) subq
```

output:

```
| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_date   | col_value | carry_forward_value |
| ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ---------- | --------- | ------------------- |
| ES    | A1    | X1    | Y1    | 2019-12-31 | 0         | 0                   |
| ES    | A1    | X1    | Y1    | 2020-01-01 |           | 0                   |
| ES    | A1    | X1    | Y1    | 2020-01-31 | 3         | 3                   |
| ES    | A1    | X1    | Y1    | 2019-02-01 | 4         | 4                   |
| ES    | A1    | X1    | Y1    | 2019-03-31 |           | 4                   |
| ES    | A1    | X1    | Y1    | 2019-02-29 |           | 4                   |
| ES    | A1    | X1    | Y1    | 2019-03-01 |           | 4                   |
| ES    | A1    | X1    | Y1    | 2019-04-01 | 6         | 6                   |
| ES    | A1    | X1    | Y1    | 2019-04-30 |           | 6                   |
```

Comment: Thanks Zealous. By the way, I think you missed to add the partitions that I have mentioned in my question (`PARTITION BY Col_1,Col_2,Col_3,Col_4`). Can you please add this also to your answer as we might get same/different dates for another `Col_1,Col_2,Col_3,Col_4` set of values @zealous

Comment: Just curious - we don't need to add `PARTITION BY Col_1,Col_2,Col_3,Col_4` in `max(Col_Value) over (partition by rn)`? Will it work in all scenarios?

Comment: @SarathAvanavu if this is the answer of your problem then please accept it.

Comment: Without adding `PARTITION BY Col_1,Col_2,Col_3,Col_4` in `max(Col_Value) over (partition by rn)` it is giving wrong result. When I added this condition, it worked like a charm. Thanks Zealous. You can make this edit in your answer. Meanwhile I am accepting this answer and plus one.

Answer (score 1):

Hive supports ignoring `NULL` values on `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUES()`.  Alas, it does not support this on `LAG()`, but you can use `LAST_VALUE()`:

```
select ct.*,
       last_value(Col_Value, TRUE) over (partition by Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4 order by Col_Date)
from carray_table ct;
```

This should do exactly what you want without subqueries.

Note:  The Hive syntax is non-standard.  The standard syntax would be `IGNORE NULLS`, rather than a second argument.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Worked like a charm. Plus 1

Comment: @SarathAvanavu . . . I think this is the better solution for Hive, which is why I answered.